# How do I instalI xfe-1.43.2.tar.gz?

Tags: bash, upgrade, tar, gzip

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
I installed xfe file manager with: sudo apt install xfe version 1.42.
I would like to upgrade it to version 1.43.2.
I downloaded xfe-1.43.2.tar.gz and extracted it.
I gave execute permissions to the files I tried running below.
I don't know what I have to do to perform the upgrade?
I've tried this:
I changed the path to the directory I extracted it to and ran:

```
rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... no
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
./configure: line 6350: intltool-update: command not found
checking for intltool-update... no
checking for intltool-merge... no
checking for intltool-extract... no
configure: error: The intltool scripts were not found. Please install intltool.
rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2$
```

I noticed some no's but figured it might install anyway?
I guessed that intltool stood for international tool which I don't need.

So I ran: INSTALL and got:

```
rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2$ ./INSTALL
./INSTALL: line 1: Installation: command not found
./INSTALL: line 2: ABOUT-NLS: command not found
./INSTALL: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `C'
./INSTALL: line 4: `Copyright (C) 1994, 1995, 1996, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004, 2005 Free'
rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2$
```

Ran /autogensh and got:

```
rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ /home/rob/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2/autogen.sh
/home/rob/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2/autogen.sh: 7: /home/rob/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2/autogen.sh: aclocal: not found
/home/rob/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2/autogen.sh: 8: /home/rob/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2/autogen.sh: autoconf: not found
/home/rob/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2/autogen.sh: 9: /home/rob/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2/autogen.sh: automake: not found
rob@rob-MS-7721:~$
```

I did the same with ltmain.sh file and got:

```
rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2$ /home/rob/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2/ltmain.sh
/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
It repeated the above several times and a whole bunch of other errors before I canceled it.
rob@rob-MS-7721:~/Ub18/File-Mangers/xfe/xfe-1.43.2$
```

There are not other .sh files and I have no idea what other Executable files to run or what information I need to give them if I did.
I don't know where to go from here.
How do I install the downloaded xfe-1.43.2.tar.gz?
Thanks, Rob

Comment: could you please clarify the issue. latest version v desired functionality. I would note that  xfe is  listed as obsolete on a quick google (sorry) What are you trying to achieve??

Comment: `./INSTALL` is likely a text file *describing how to* install the software - it's not something you should be trying to execute

Comment: I am trying to find a File Manger that I like better than Nautilus (Files) File Manager. I have tried Dolphin and Thunar and went back to Nautilus. xfe appears to be more to my liking so I am trying to upgrade it. I have never been able to successfully install (run) a tar.gz download. So, I'm also trying to learn how to do that?

Comment: You need to install ALL the dependencies that `./configure` complains about, until it successfully runs and creates a `Makefile`. Then you run `make all` and finally `sudo make install`.

Comment: Thanks steeldriver. The first one it complains about is: gawk. What is or how do I install gawk?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - you **don't** need to install things where the configure output just says `checking for ... no`; only for those (like `intltool`) that cause it to error out

Comment: At the bottom it says to install the `intltool`.  `sudo apt install intltool`

Comment: Thanks steeldriver and Terrance. I think I'm on the right track now. I've installed intltool and libFOX-1.6. and ran ./configure after each. The next error is xcb-aux - this might take awhile...

Comment: I spoke too soon. I tried to install xcb-aux and got: rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ sudo apt install xcb-aux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xcb-aux
rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ How do I find xcb-aux?

Comment: It's provided by package `libxcb-util-dev`

Comment: I installed rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ sudo apt install libxcb-util-dev
and tried installing xcb-aux again and still got: rob@rob-MS-7721:~$ sudo apt install xcb-aux
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xcb-aux
rob@rob-MS-7721:~$

Comment: Try downloading it from [focal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/xfe/download). The package is not tied to the distribution other than its dependencies. You could always purge the package if it doesn't work. dpkg -i <package> (don't forget the theme package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking over the installation, this is what I was able to come up with for the installation.

After you download the xfe-1.43.2.tar.gz file you extract it.

```
tar zxvf xfe-1.43.2.tar.gz
```

Enter the folder created

```
cd xfe-1.43.2/
```

Install the prerequisites needed for the building

```
sudo apt install build-essential libxcb-util-dev libfox-1.6-dev libx11-xcb-dev intltool
```

Now all you should have to do is the configure, make and make install

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then all you should have to do is run the `xfe`

[image]

[image]

Comment: WOW! Thanks Terrance. It worked exactly as you said it would.

Comment: Thank you too steeldriver. You and Terrance taught me a lot about how to install tar.gz files as well.

Comment: @Rob You're very welcome!  Make sure here to put an @ in front of the person's name when you are trying to send them a message here so that they will see it.  =)

Comment: Ok. Thanks again @steeldriver.